# The density of the image of a unitary irrep (a generalization of Burnside's theorem)

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, unitary-representations

*I asked the following [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4326565/does-the-image-of-a-unitary-irrep-span-all-unitary-operators) on MSE and never got an answer.*

I am curious if there are any generalizations of Burnside's theorem ([If $(\pi,V)$ is irreducible, then $\pi(G)$ spans $\operatorname{End}(V)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3176651/if-pi-v-is-irreducible-then-pig-spans-operatornameendv)) from finite dim irreps to infinite dim irreps.

My question is in general but to make things more concrete we can consider an example. Let $\pi: \operatorname{SE}_3 \to \mathcal{U}(V)$ be a unitary irrep of the special Euclidean group $\operatorname{SE}_3 = \mathbb{R}^3 \rtimes \operatorname{SO}(3)$. To get a non-trivial irrep we know $V$ must be infinite dimensional. Does the image $\pi(\operatorname{SE}_3)$ span a dense subspace of the set of all unitary operators $\mathcal{U}(V)$?

It's possible that this is still too general; in that case suppose $V$ is the Hilbert space $L^2(S^2)$, the square integrable functions on the sphere. Does the image span a dense subspace now?

A related question is given here: [Is this a basis for the bounded operators on $ L^2(\mathbb{R}) $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4303824/is-this-a-basis-for-the-bounded-operators-on-l2-mathbbr)

Comment: Why do you say $V$ must be infinite-dimensional?  Why not just extend a non-trivial, finite-dimensional representation of $\operatorname{SO}(3)$ trivially across $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: perhaps OP wants the representation to be faithful?